# MySql - Insert only if some fields are not insered yet

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table, with field1(id), field2(name) and field3(surname).

Id like to insert the value only if the pair field2 and field3 are not already insered. How can I do it?

INSERT IGNORE doesnt work because the field1 is int autoincrement and every INSERT is different.

P.S. I'd like to get rid about REPLACE INTO, because it doesnt make sense "rewrite" data if it already exist

Cheers

EDIT

Table structure
id = INT primary
name = VARCHAR 
surname = VARCHAR

name and surname can't be each UNIQUE (i can have 2 name or surname with the same values). What i want is that the pair name and surname haven't the same value.

es :

0 Marco Cordi (OK)

1 Marco Daghine (OK)

2 Fabio Cordi (OK)

3 Marco Cordi (NOT OK, is already definied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone to answer this question for you, you need to post your actual table structure (including any primary/unique keys that exist).

If your table has no primary/unique keys, then the only way to do this is to run a SELECT and see if you get any rows back, and perform the INSERT if there are no rows found.

If you want the rows in your table to be unique on field2 and field3, then you should create a unique index on those columns (which can be done with the [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) query).

**EDIT**: you want a unique index, not on each of those fields individually, but on BOTH of them.  You want to run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_name` (`field2`, `field3`);
```

Once you have done that, you can use INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: Added some further info! Check it out

Comment: Edited - a single unique index that covers both columns will do exactly what you want!

Comment: Uhm ok, nice shoot! but with this method i have a key on VARCHAR elements. Is not better have only INT on one key and use a replace into? In computional time terms, i mean :)

Comment: "Better" - no, it shouldn't have any negative impact.  This is exactly what unique indexes are meant to do.  Any other method of accomplishing the same thing would be "worse".

Comment: Uhm...but the solution by John K. is more performant than put UNIQUE keys, no?

Comment: If there are no indexes on name or surname, then no, it would actually be much slower.  If there was a non-unique index on both column, it would be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

```
update myTable
set name = coalesce(name, 'newname'), 
surname = coalesce(surname, 'newsurname') 
where id = myID;
```

(Updated)

```
insert into myTable(name, surname) 
values ('newname', 'newsurname') 
where NOT EXISTS (select id from myTable where name = newname and surname = surname) ;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean UPDATE if the fields don't already have entries.

Comment: ??? I don't have ID...i just need to search in a table if name and surname values are already insered. Else, i put them on DB.

Comment: If you mean literally... update only if 'both' fields are empty then it would be :  update myTable
set name = 'newname', 
surname = 'newsurname' 
where id = myID and name is null and surname is null ;

Comment: Oh... I see... then it would be insert into myTable(name, surname)  values ('newname', 'newsurname') where id not in (select id from myTable where name > '' and surname > '') ;

Comment: Uhm ok, so in that case is better to use Replace Into :)

Comment: The 'Updated' sql above will insert a new record with name and surname into the table only if that new name and surname don't already exist in the table.

Comment: Yes...but i think is better do a scan with replace into and at least do a replace rather than do a insert on SELECT (so, somethings like 2 scan in the table)

Comment: I fixed a problem above with the updated sql... That will insert if one doesn't exist already... You can't really "replace" one since it's using the name and surname to do the lookup.  If the name or surname has changed, you don't have any way to determine which one to replace (unless you do some type of partial match on the names).